# Intersection point of a line with cardinal interpolation and a line with linear interpolation in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, line

I need to find the intersection point of a line with cardinal interpolation

i.e.

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
.interpolate("cardinal")
.x(function(d, i) { return x(d.x); })
.y(function(d, i) { return y(d.y); });
```

and a line between two points

i.e.

```
svg.append('line').attr('x1',x1).attr('y1',y1).attr('x2',x2).attr('y2',y2)
```

Is there any way to find the intersection of the above mentioned lines? Or Can I get the equation of the cardinal spline given the default value for cardinal interpolation in D3 is '0.7' ?

Comment: The [intersection library](http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/math/intersection/) may help here.